# Django form: if searchForm

Tags: django

I got a model, for simplicity only 1 field shown here:

```
class Family(models.Model):
    myboolean = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is my form for that model:

```
class FamilyForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.searchForm = kwargs.pop('searchForm', False)
        super(FamilyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.searchForm:
            for key in self.fields:
                self.fields[key].required = False # let the user search by whatever field he wants to
            <help needed right here>

    class Meta:
        model = models.Family
        fields = '__all__'
```

When I create the form with "searchForm = True" I get a problem with the boolean field in my model. It has a default value of "False" but of course I want to let the user search for a family without using that boolean field. When the user doesn't tick the box, I get "False". When he ticks the box I get "True". But I also need "value not needed for search". How do I do this?

Comment: push............. (okay this doesn't seem to work, lol)

Comment: Can't you use choice field?